# What's the functional difference between the "disabled" and "external" caching setting?

Tags: caching, 6

I've seen the answer elsewhere that "External lets you use varnish, etc" but what are the internal differences between external and no caching? Does external actually cache anything, or is there a difference in headers sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is like you say a difference in the headers that drupal send out. I've based this answer on Drupal 6 since it seems from the text you quote that this is the version you are referring to.

Anyways, in `bootstrap.inc`, drupal will call `drupal_page_cache_header_external` when external cache is turned on. I posted the function below since I couldn't find it on api.drupal.org

```
/**
 * Set HTTP headers in for downstream caching.
 *
 * The headers allow as much as possible in proxies and browsers without any
 * particular knowledge about the pages. Used for the external caching mode.
 */
function drupal_page_cache_header_external() {
  // Get headers set in hook_boot(). Keys are lower-case.
  $hook_boot_headers = drupal_get_header();

  $max_age = variable_get('page_cache_max_age', 0);
  drupal_set_header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' . $max_age);
  drupal_set_header('Last-Modified', gmdate(DATE_RFC1123, $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']));

  // HTTP/1.0 proxies do not support the Vary header, so prevent any caching
  // by sending an Expires date in the past. HTTP/1.1 clients ignores the
  // Expires header if a Cache-Control: max-age= directive is specified (see RFC
  // 2616, section 14.9.3).
  drupal_set_header('Expires', 'Sun, 11 Mar 1984 12:00:00 GMT');

  // Allow HTTP proxies to cache pages for anonymous users without a session
  // cookie. The Vary header is used to indicates the set of request-header
  // fields that fully determines whether a cache is permitted to use the
  // response to reply to a subsequent request for a given URL without
  // revalidation. If a Vary header has been set in hook_boot(), it is assumed
  // that the module knows how to cache the page.
  if (!isset($hook_boot_headers['vary']) && !variable_get('omit_vary_cookie', FALSE)) {
    drupal_set_header('Vary', 'Cookie');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

External caching is just a caching system that doesn't use the database tables used by Drupal to cache data, or doesn't use any table in the database used by Drupal. Example of external caching systems includes APC, eAccelerator, Memcache/Memcached, Varnish, XCache, or even a system that uses files instead of database tables.

All those systems surely cache data, or there would not be any difference between using them, and disabling the cache completely. The only difference with the standard Drupal cache system is where the data are cached.

Comment: You don't actually answer the question.

Comment: @googletorp The question body actually contains two questions, one of which is "does external actually cache anything?"

Comment: true, I guess combined we guess combined we got the perfect answer.